# How to capture stored procedure text when passing from Dephi 2006

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, delphi

HI all,

I have a large (100+) parameter list for my SP in my delphi code.  This is for MS SQL Server 2005.  For debugging purposes, I want to capture the text of the stored procedure command, so i can execute it on the SQL server and debug the SP.  Is there a way i can capture what is exactly passed to the database? I thought about using a trace, and I'll try that tomorrow if this fails, but its cumbersome to set up and sift through and catch the SP.

Thanks

Comment: Basically I want to do a copy and paste to execute it by hand on the SQL server.

Comment: How are you connecting to SQL Server? The driver you're using (Delphi's own dbexpress, ADO, third party) makes a difference. (BTW, if you have an SP that takes 100+ parameters, there's got to be a better way - that many parameters is unmanageable, IMO.)

Comment: care to provide example code?  might narrow down simplest solutions.

Comment: We use ADO to connect to MS SQL.  Not sure what the alternative to 100+ params is, maybe pass table structures?  Advice welcome!  We are passing in HL7 messages which typically have 100 or so fields.

Comment: I updated my answer - XML looks like a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the SQL Server Profiler for this. Start a new trace with default settings. Let it run while your client executes the SP. Stop the trace. Use ctrl-F and search for you SP name.

Answer (score 0):

I normally don't care for playing with the programming environment.

Profiling would be a good option if you can **identify the ClientProcessID** (the PID showing in Task Manager of your client program) - that should narrow it down enough.

Another alternative I like is to simply capture it at the SQL Server end.

Sample proc

```
create proc takes3params
@a int, @b varchar(100), @c datetime
as
select @a, @b, @c
```

Becomes

```
alter proc takes3params
@a int, @b varchar(100), @c datetime
as
insert capture_takes3params(a,b,c) select @a, @b, @c  -- << -- added
select @a, @b, @c
```

The support table is a mirror of the params, with 2 additional control columns

```
create table capture_takes3params(
id int identity primary key, captured datetime default(getdate()), -- control
a int, b varchar(100), c datetime
)
```

This doesn't work when the proc has defaults though.

---

#### EDIT

> We use ADO to connect to MS SQL. Not sure what the alternative to 100+ params is, maybe pass table structures? Advice welcome! We are passing in HL7 messages which typically have 100 or so fields. –

Table valued parameters are only available from SQL Server 2008 onwards, from what I recall.  That seems unwieldy as well from Delphi - I would instead look at a single XML parameter dissected in TSQL, which 2005+ has good support for.

Comment: So your solution is `insert capture_takes100plusparams(a,b,c,...ddd, eee, fff...)`? Doesn't seem like a good one to me; may be just me, though. ;)

Comment: @Ken - it is one way. It doesn't require Profiler to be installed, does not "accidentally" kill a system with an incorrect trace setup, does not require application change etc. I find I can script it very quickly when needed, and at times leave it to capture rarely executed SPs (instead of leaving profiler running)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of your reasoning. As I said, it's probably just me, but an SP with 100 or more params seems really bad to me, and writing your `insert capture_takes100plusparams` would make things even worse. But I didn't downvote your answer, either. :)

Comment: I ended up using server profiler.  Was far simpler than any other solution. Thanks!